# Handlebars if statement going to else statement when if statement is correct

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I am currently trying to write an if else block in handlebars for a messaging part of my social media app. I am passing through messages from the controller and for the example I am using, there is an empty array but for some reason it keeps going to the else statement. I have tried a number of different combinations for this to work but it keeps going to the else statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
{{#if messages.length}}
  <p>if statement</p>
  <div class="message-container card" id="{{this._id}}">
    <p> Start a new conversation </p>
  </div>
{{else}}
  <p>else statement</p>
  {{#each messages}}

    <div class="message-container card" id="{{this._id}}">

      <div class="profile-picture">
          <img src={{user.profilePicture}} width="100"
            height="100"
            class="rounded-circle"/>
      </div>
      <div class="message-header">
        <span class="name">{{this.sender.firstName}} {{this.sender.lastName}}</span>
        <div class="date-sent">{{this.createdAt}}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="post-body">
        <p class="message">
          {{this.message}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I think perhaps your logic is inverted, as it stands the `if` block would be executed if messages is _not_ empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That's correct. If there is an empty array it should go to the `else` statement because an empty array will have length of `0` which is `falsy`.

In your code you have

```
{{#if messages.length}}
    print this if array is not empty because
    message.length is not zero
{{#else}}
    print this if array is empty
    because message.length is zero
{{/if}}
```

So it is behaving correctly.

If you intend to do the opposite either swap the code inside the `if` and `else` blocks or replace `#if` with `#unless`.